# Use Redis MQ of ServiceStack and Signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redis, signalr

Where can use [Redis MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis) and where can use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) in large-scale project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used signalR and used parts of ServiceStack. took a quick look at Redis MQ. I think these are unrelated

1. SignalR - server to client (browser) messaging and abstracting out details of the channel being used (websockets/long polling etc) based on the browser and server technology. lets you easily build apps where server can push information back to clients. In a scale out scenario, SignalR uses a sort of pub/sub messaging to handle clients that may be connected in different nodes. It can make use of Redis over a backplane (just one of the options - others are SQL server or Azure service bus)
2. Redis MQ - basically a MQ implementation over Redis? From the page you linked:

> A redis-based message queue client/server that can be hosted in any
>   .NET or ASP.NET application.

Redis itself is a in-memory NoSQL store (though you can have it flush to disk) - super fast and a great fit for certain scenarios. And it also has pub/sub primitives.

So with that said, your question isn't quite clear. Maybe you can elaborate on what you're looking for? How do you plan to use pub/sub?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im looking for best way in large-scale project "push information to clients".

Comment: Clients == In browser javascript clients? then go with SignalR with one of the scaleout scenarios that it supports.

Comment: so, Use publish info to browser or scaleout scenario, Where can use Redis MQ?(example in real world)